# Permanent character in html form test inout

Tags: php, html

I am making a form that will save to an xml file using php.  I have gotten everything to work great, but I want to automatically add a $ to the input field so the user does not have to.  How can I start out with a $ as the first character?  (Only dealing with whole dollars so I don't need to worry about decimals).  This is the simple text input I have made.

```
    <label>Price:</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="txtPrice" />
```

Comment: $data = "$".intval($_POST['txtPrice']);?

Comment: it storing in db, it should not be sorted with the **$**

Comment: Won't MySQL just ignore the $? Nope:) Just wanted to play devil's advicate.

Comment: I was just giving an alternative. for displaying it later. Intval should regardless be used to ensure user-input sanity.

Answer (score 2):

Use `::before` in CSS

```
label::before {
    content:"$";
    color: blue;
}


<label><input type="text" name="txtPrice" id='input' /></labl>.
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cUCBC/2/)**

Comment: Wouldn't just using a label be better? If they are trying to support older IE I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<label>Price:</label><br />
<input type="text" name="txtPrice" value="$" />
```

Or this:

```
<label>Price:</label><br />
$<input type="text" name="txtPrice" value="$" />
```

Comment: user can still overwrite the $, if that's an issue

Answer (score 0):

I was just having fun with this one, but it puts the $ in the box.

http://jsfiddle.net/NGH7d/3/

Not sure if this will work in IE6-8, also you probably need to adjust the numbers around.

```
    <label class="money">$</label><input type="text" id="txtprice" name="txtPrice" id='input' />

    label.money{
color: blue;
float:left;
position:relative;
left:12px;
top:3px;
    }

    #txtprice {
        padding-left:12px;
    }
```